# Splitting a string in c# and accessing data at a certain index

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, split

So I have a string as such...

```
"Opp#: 103 -- Member: mem1-- Patient: patient1-- Room: n.10 -- Time: 16:45"
```

Is there's a way to split the string so that I can access the number '103' (which fyi  changes depending on user activity).I'm only interested in said number and have been trying to play around with the split function and arrays but no luck :(

Comment: which parts of the string are static?

Comment: If it is always in that format, you could do some substring work, and pull it out that way.

Comment: Why split? Why not regex?

Comment: Is Opp# always at the start of the string and is always followed by a space and then by the number?

Comment: or a regular expression would work as well.

Comment: Opp#:, Member:, Patient:, Room: and Time: are static, they just name the values that are supplied by the database. So i basically have a database from which values: 103, mem1, patient1, n.10 and 16:45 are pulled. Note that the "--" are just appended to the string in order to space the data out.

Comment: @steve yes Opp#: is always at the start of the string andis always followed by a space then the number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the row I identified the following pattern:
Each row has multiple fields separated by `--`
Each field is a name value pair where the name is separated from value by `:`

So:

```
string[] fieldSeparators = new string[] { "--" };
string[] nameValueSeparators = new string[] {":"};
var fieldsArray = row.Split(fieldSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Dictionary fields = new Dictionary<string,string>();
foreach (var field in fieldsArray)
{
  var tokens = field.Split(nameValueSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
  if (tokens.Length >= 2)
     fields[tokens[0]/*.Trim()*/] = tokens[1]/*.Trim()*/;
}
```

The value you want (as string) can be obtained from dictionary with:

```
fields["Opp#"]
```

This does more than you say you need but what looks as structured data *should* be structured.

Answer (score 2):

Try to split `--` and take the `First()` element from list. On that element do a split at `:` and take the second element (`[1]`).

```
string data = "Opp#: 103 -- Member: mem1-- Patient: patient1-- Room: n.10 -- Time: 16:45";
var elements = data.Split(new []{"--"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
var opp = Int32.Parse(elements.First().Split(':')[1].Trim());
```

---

As @steve sugested you can do split only 1 time at `' '`, if you are sure that is always followed by a number.

```
var opp = Int32.Parse(data.Split(' ')[1]);
```

---

Also you can create an Model to match that type of data. And to create a function to Deserialize that `string` into `model`. In this way you can have access to any property when you want.
Example:

```
string data = "Opp#: 103 -- Member: mem1-- Patient: patient1-- Room: n.10 -- Time: 16:45";
var model = new ModelDeserialize("--"," ", 1).Deserialize(data);
```

This will desearilize that type of string in `Model`

```
public class ModelDeserialize
{
    private string _elementsSeparator;
    private string _dataSeparator;
    private int _valueIdx;

    public ModelDeserialize(string elementsSeparator, string dataSeparator, int valueIdx)
    {
        _elementsSeparator = elementsSeparator;
        _dataSeparator = dataSeparator;
        _valueIdx = valueIdx;
    }

    public Model Deserialize(string data)
    {
        var idx = 0;
        var separatedElements = data.Split(new[] { _elementsSeparator }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var model = new Model();
        model.Opp = Int32.Parse(Value(separatedElements[idx++]));
        model.Member = Value(separatedElements[idx++]);
        model.Patient = Value(separatedElements[idx++]);
        model.Room = Value(separatedElements[idx++]);
        model.Time = Value(separatedElements[idx]);
        return model;
    }

    private string Value(string element)
    {
        return element.Split(new[] { _dataSeparator }, StringSplitOptions.None)[_valueIdx].Trim();
    }
}
```

`Model`, can have a more significant name.

```
public class Model
{
    public int Opp { get; set; }
    public string Member { get; set; }
    public string Patient { get; set; }
    public string Room { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well, if you want to use Split then split just one time at space and take the second entry

Answer (score 0):

```
string content = "Opp#: 103 -- Member: mem1-- Patient: patient1-- Room: n.10 -- Time: 16:45";
string result = content.Split('-')[0].Split(':')[1].Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to get the value

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex oppNumber = new Regex(@"^Opp#: (<?number>\d)+",RegexOptions.Compiled);

public int ParseValue(string line)
{
    return Int32.Parse(oppNumber.Match(line).Groups["number"].Value);
}
```

There's no error checking in this example, so you will want to add additional code to deal with badly formatted data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try regular expressions:

```
    string s = "Opp#: 103 -- Member: mem1-- Patient: patient1-- Room: n.10 -- Time: 16:45";

    Regex rex = new Regex(@"Opp#: (\d+) -- Member: ([^-]+)-- Patient: ([^-]+)-- Room: ([^-]+)-- Time: (.....)");

    var match = rex.Match(s);

    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);  //103
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2]);  //mem1
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[3]);  //patient1
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[4]);  //n.10
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[5]);  //16:45
```